# Turning a multi Column Table into a Key name Value tuple table, in postgresql

Tags: database, postgresql

I Have a large number of queries some of which can take half an hour to run, many of these queries return over 20 or so columns( yes they are normalised). I am interested in storing all of this data in a single table, in the format for Timestamp, name, value, the reson for this is for later automation on the data.

However when I have a query that returns

```
T1, V1t1, V2t1, V3t1
T2, V1t2, v2t2, v3t2
--   --    --    --
```

and I wish to have the data in format

```
T1, Name(V1), V1t1
T1, Name(V2), V2t1
T1, Name(V3), V3t1
T2, Name(V1), V1t2
T2, Name(V2), V2t2
T2, Name(V3), V3t2
```

I know I Could do this by doing a union on selects for each value v1, v2 and v3,

however I am interested in speed and would like to refrain from issuing 3 queries where  I can get the data(albeit in the wroung format) in one..   or in the real case refrain from issuing 20-30 queries where it can be done in one.

so the question is , is there a way to do this apart from dumping into a temporary table and running subsequent selects onto the relevant columns of the table and unioning them together..

would this be possible with a custom built postgresql function?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve what you want with a variant of the following query.

```
CREATE TABLE data
(
   sampleTime timestamptz,
   value1 numeric,
   value2 numeric,
   value3 numeric
);

INSERT INTO data(sampleTime,value1,value2,value3) values(now(),1,2,3);
INSERT INTO data(sampleTime,value1,value2,value3) values(now(),4,5,6);

SELECT data.sampleTime,
   CASE
      WHEN generate_series = 1 THEN 'value1'
      WHEN generate_series = 2 THEN 'value2'
      ELSE 'value3'
   END AS key,
   CASE
      WHEN generate_series = 1 THEN value1
      WHEN generate_series = 2 then value2
      ELSE value3 
   END AS value
FROM data,generate_series(1,3)
ORDER BY data.sampleTime,generate_series
```

Answer (score 2):

This is completely doable with a custom PostgreSQL function. You may also be able to use the `tablefunc` module and use the [`crosstab` function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/3002579#3002579) to do what you want. It looks like you're trying to accomplish an unpivot in PostgreSQL, so you may get more use out of this mailing list thread [Unpivot with PostgreSQL](https://lists.launchpad.net/dhis2-users/msg00112.html)